# How do I remove duplicates of letters in string in a case insensitive way so that the letter appears only once?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a function that removes duplicate letters regardless of it is uppercase or lowercase.

If my input string is **`FoxfoXtAg`**, the expected output will be **`FoxtAg`**. My  output is **`FoxfXtAg`** which only removes the lowercase **`o`**.

I have also used `.toLowerCase()`, which gives the expected output, but changes the case.

```
let duplicateLetter = (string) => {

 //check if string only contains letters
 if (!string.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/gi)) {
  console.log('does not match')
 }

 //check to see if it is a string
 if(typeof(string) !== 'string') {
  return 'Please return a string'
 }

  //make string lowercase (couldn't find check for case insensitive)
  string = string.toLowerCase()

 //this gets rid of spaces as duplicate characters
 string = string.split(' ').join('')

 //creates set with only unique elements
 let noDuplicates = [...new Set(string)];


 return noDuplicates.join('')

}

console.log(duplicateLetter("FoxfoXtAg"));
```

Comment: "*If my input string is "FoxfoXtAg", the expected output will be "FoxtAg". My expected output is "FoxfXtAg" which only removes the lowercase o.*" ...I assume that the second string is the *actual* output, which is not what you want? Otherwise you have two different expected results

Comment: Sorry, the output of my current function is "FoxfXtAg", but I want the expected output of "FoxtAg". I hope this clarifies that issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let str = `AbraCadABraAlakAzam`
let op = /^[a-z]+$/gi.test(str) && str
         .split('')
         .reduce((out,inp)=>{
              if(!(out[inp.toLowerCase()] || out[inp.toUpperCase()])){
                out[inp]=1
              }
              return out;
          },{})

console.log(Object.keys(op).join(''))
```

***So here the idea is***

1. First using regex test string contains only alphabets or not.
2. [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) breaks string into array.
3. we create a key based on **first occurrence** of character.
4. when next time ***same character*** appears we use [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and [`toUppercase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) to check if it is already there. so by this way in output we can keep the first occurrence of character while removing duplication.
5. In the end we take the keys using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and using [`Join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) we change array back to string.

Answer (score 2):

You could transform your string into an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). This allows us to iterate over it letter by letter.

To do that iteration, the best option would be [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which is used to convert an array into a single result (like a string).

Inside the `reduce()` would be case-insensitive regex to determine if we've already "used" that letter or not. We only add the letter to the output if it's new.

```js
function removeDuplicates(str) {

  let result = Array.from(str).reduce((output, letter) => {
    let re = new RegExp(letter, "i");   //Create case-insensitive regex
    return re.test(output)              //Does our output include that letter already?
      ? output                          //Yes - don't modify the output
      : output+letter                   //No  - add it to the output
  }, "");
  
  return result;

}

console.log( removeDuplicates("HELLOworld") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the input and expected output at the question you can convert the input string to an `Array`, `.reverse()` then `.join()` the array, use `RegExp` `/([a-z])(?=\1|.*\1)/ig` with `.replace()` to match `a-z` followed by the captured character or followed by a character that is not the captured character then then capatured character, convert the string to an array again, `.reverse()` then `.join()`

```js
const removeDuplicates = (str, r = a => a.reverse().join``) => 
  r([...r([...str]).replace(/([a-z])(?=\1|.*\1)/ig,'')]);

console.log(removeDuplicates("FoxfoXtAg"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
    
public class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String text =  "Good Morning";
    
        char str[] = text.toCharArray();
        HashSet<Character> s = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        boolean flag = true;
        boolean flag1 = true;
        
        for(Character word: str) {
            flag = s.contains(Character.toLowerCase(word));
            flag1 = s.contains(Character.toUpperCase(word));
            
            if(!flag && !flag1) {
            s.add(word );
            }
        }
        for(char word: s) {
            System.out.print(word ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: javascript and java is not the same thing